# Why not Qt for programming beginners?

Tags: qt

I've heard from good sources that Qt is not good to learn to code, because it doesn't let you see or learn about what's behind all the work that qt does for you. We all know that Qt is very powerful, It does all the work for you. So is it really important to know what's behind the scenes of every qt function? Is there a good alternative to Qt that let you code the basics and achieve the same result (GUI design, Graphics, ...)?

Comment: There's a difference between learning a language (C++) and an API/library/tool (Qt). If you want to learn C++, you should probably focus on C++ (and not with distractions like Qt).

Comment: I didn't mean just c++ but programming in general

Comment: Then replace "C++" with any other programming language. If you are talking about theoretical concepts (that is, computer science), then Qt doesn't really offer anything extra that would help with that. Qt is a useful tool, but there isn't anything specific about it that would help a beginner learn about software development. It just presents an extra burden for the beginner to learn. If you cut Qt out, then the beginner doesn't have to learn Qt **and** whatever the other subject is. Learning two things takes longer than learning one thing.

Comment: What "good sources" did you hear this from? They're not very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is great frameworks. Easy to use of course. For expert C++ programmers, Qt make their life a lot easier, like what they say *Code Less, Create More, Deploy Everywhere*. But, for beginners, Qt hide **the hard way** behind C++ programming.

Think that a program is a car and Qt is a set of exellent tools for building it. An expert mechanic will say, "What an easy way to build a car?" because **he find** the tool is very helpful. A beginner mechanic will say the same (at the first time), because he **doesn't find** any hard work to do. But, after doing something he will say, "Err, what is this tool? How can I use this?" because he doesn't have the knowledge to use the tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to learn how to program you should do just that, learn the basics with any programming language and then, when you kind of understand what higher level functions are doing you can start learning to use extra libraries and frameworks.

If you end up not really understanding what are you doing then the moment you don't have access to the framework you won't know what to do. But if you really learn the basics first, it becomes really easy to translate that knowledge into other programming languages and tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are some aspects in programming. You can learn low level programming, application level programming, GUI programming, algorithm programming... So for every goal you can use different approaches and tools. For algorithm you can use Python, for low level programming you can use C. For application level you can use C++. For GUI programming you can use Qt. Every tool use they own abstract level. What behind that level is hidden for a reason of simplicity development process.